# Exit routine implementation for Android App

Tags: android, back-stack, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am having trouble implementing an exit routine for my Android Application.The application is based on BluetoothLeGatt example and i am developing a heart rate sensor application.
I have DeviceScanActivity(has UI) and it fires an intent to DeviceControlActivity(without UI). When DeviceControlActivity is executing I am not able to stop that activity by pressing the back button. As this activity does not have a UI i could not implement

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

If I press Home button directly, the UI exits but is still accepting data from the BLE device.How do I exit my application cleanly?

Comment: If you do not need the UI then why are you using activity, use a simple service which runs in background and you can stop it when done

Comment: I guess it's because the API documentation shows an example inheriting from ListActivity. You should put a piece of code in the onHide method of your activity to stopping BLE activity.